# if statement, check if value starts with an integer

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to set property `pAPIcall_Filter` to true if `getROL_ID` starts with an integer.

```
if (getROL_ID.search(/^\d/)){
    log.debug("Starts with an integer ");
    next.setProperty('pAPIcall_Filter', true);
} else {
    log.debug("Does not start with an integer ");
    next.setProperty('pAPIcall_Filter', false);
}
```

Inputting values `KANEJ2` and `573871`, both return true

Comment: `.search()` returns the index of the first match. If there's no match, it returns `-1`, and `-1` evaluates to `true` in an `if` test.

Comment: "*I am sending these two values, KANEJ2 and 573871, the condition thinks they both start with an integer.*" I don't believe this can be correct, since, when used in this algorithm, the latter should evaluate to `0`, which is falsy. The only instance which I could foresee this being true is if `typeof getROL_ID !== 'string'` and it has its own `search()` instance method which behaves differently than `String.prototype.search()` does.

Comment: Use `.match()`, not `.search()`

Comment: Remember that `-1` is an integer but `-` will not be matched by `\d`

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to check a static *string*.

Here is an example.

```js
let getROL_ID = 'KANEJ2'
let b = '0123456789'.includes(getROL_ID[0])

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `search` returns `-1` (which is not zero, nor falsy), this is a `true` expression.

You should use:

```js
if (getROL_ID.match(/^\d/)) { ... }
```

Or, better yet:

```js
if (/^\d/.test(getROL_ID)) { ... }
```

---

If you want to correct your logic, compare the result to `-1`:

```js
if (getROL_ID.search(/^\d/) !== -1) {
  log.debug("Starts with an integer ");
  next.setProperty('pAPIcall_Filter', true);
} else {
  log.debug("Does not start with an integer ");
  next.setProperty('pAPIcall_Filter', false);
}
```